# Blazor Server - When is blazor-error-ui displayed?

Tags: c#, error-handling, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm slightly confused about how `blazor-error-ui` works in practice. I understand that it's hidden by default because of CSS (via `display: none`), but I can't seem to get it to appear by causing errors in the application.

According to the [Blazor docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#detailed-errors-during-development):

> The `blazor-error-ui` element is normally hidden due to the presence of the `display: none` style of the `blazor-error-ui` CSS class in the site's stylesheet [...] **When an error occurs, the framework applies `display: block` to the element.**

Emphasis mine.

The docs say that an error should cause the `blazor-error-ui` div to have its `display` property set to `block`, but throwing an exception takes me to an developer exception page, and doesn't actually display the div at all. If I set the environment to `Release`, it takes me to the `/Error` page, instead.

So, when does the `blazor-error-ui` div actually get shown? When Blazor itself has an internal error?

Answer (score 2):

*I won't mark this as accepted, because I couldn't find an official source for this, and my own testing yielded mixed results so far.*

It seems like errors that occur within events can trigger `blazor-error-ui`, but those thrown from page lifecycle methods don't.

For example:

Clicking on a `<button>` element that has an `@onclick=[...]` method defined that throws an exception causes `blazor-error-ui` to appear.

**However**, throwing an exception directly from a `@page`'s lifecycle methods (i.e. `OnInitializedAsync()`) appear to **not** trigger `blazor-error-ui`.

I'm unsure if this is intended behavior or not, since the docs don't seem to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

As I know the developer exception page shouldn't be used in production mode so for this purpose `blazor-error-ui` may be used in Blazor Application

In your case exception redirects you to developer exception page so to see `blazor-error-ui` div block you should disable developer exception page

Comment: In a Release environment (with the developer exception page disabled), I just get redirected to the `/Error` page. If I disable *that* page, I just get a blank page instead of having the `blazor-error-ui` div appear.

Comment: Check if you use any custom exception handling middleware in your application. It can blocks ```blazor-error-ui```

Comment: As far as I know, I don't have any. I'm using the basic Blazor Server project from Visual Studio and haven't done anything related to error handling myself.

Comment: ```blazor-error-ui``` div block implemented in default _Layout.cshtml. 
If in your page you set null or custom layout, error block also will not be displayed